# Validate RSA key against password without PHPSeclib

Tags: php, openssl, phpseclib

I try to validate if a passphrase works with a private key in PHP.

Right now the solution is simply to use phpseclib and do this:

```
$rsa = new \phpseclib\Crypt\RSA();
$rsa->setPassword($passphrase);
$res = $rsa->loadKey($privateKeyString);
```

and check if $res is false. This works fine but I want to get rid of phpseclib and use native PHP functionality. How can I achieve that? I tried openssl_pkey_get_private() which did not work.

I only expect RSA keys (like "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----")...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A key file starting with "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" is encoded using PKCS#1 format, which cannot be recognized by PHP's openssl extension. (It requires the key file in PKCS#8 format. In theory, openssl can read PKCS#1 format files, but PHP does not export the corresponding function.)

Therefore, you have to convert it in order to use the file.

```
openssl pkcs8 -in path/to/your/key -topk8 -out path/to/output/file
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This worked for me! If anyone uses an OPENSSH key btw. this won't work as openssl does not understand OPENSSH keys. These first need to be converted by `ssh-keygen -p -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -m pem`